# I am trying to Calculate for each year the standard deviation and average return in R

Tags: r

I started learning R three days ago so pls bear with me.... if you see any flaws in my code or calculations please call them out.

I have tried this, but get a error message every time:

```
table.AnnualizedReturns(Apple.Monthly.Returns[, 2:3, drop = FALSE], scale = 12, 
                    Rf = 0, geometric = TRUE, digits = 4)
```

Error in checkData(R) :
The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.

As you can clearly see I have no clue what I am doing.

This is every line of code I have written this far:

```
Dates <- Data_Task2$`Names Date`[1801:2270]
as.numeric(Dates)
Dates <- ymd(Dates)
Monthly.Return <- Data_Task2$Returns[1801:2270]
Monthly.Return <- as.numeric(Monthly.Return)
Apple.Monthly.Returns <- data.frame(Dates, Monthly.Return)
Log.return = log(Monthly.Return + 1)
Apple.Monthly.Returns$Log.return = log(Apple.Monthly.Returns$Monthly.Return + 1)
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making an R example that folks can help with, including a sample of data and what packages you're using

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Tidyverse and specifically dplyr (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/).

This gets you to a good starting point:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/03/using-r-quickly-calculating-summary-statistics-with-dplyr/